# How can I select a frequency if the frequency range is given?

Tags: signal-processing, frequency

I am working on a RFID project.  The RFID tags that i am using are UHF whose frequency range is given `i.e. 860-960` MHZ.  How can i find the exact frequency on which a tag is working?.  Does the value of frequency change with distance?.  The only thing i have is RSSI, which i can measured from my equipment at any distance from the tag within the reading capacity of the reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive RFID tags do not select their frequency. It is completely determined by the reader generating a carrier signal. The 860-960 MHz range indicates it's a passive UHF tag. Depending on your physical location and regulatory requirements, the tag will respond at a single channel (frequency) within that band. Most tag readers report tag reads with optional meta data, such as the channel the tag was read on.

If the reader doesn't support this, you would need some advanced instrumentation to sniff the transaction. This can be accomplished with a filed probe, directional coupler + diode detector, or real time spectrum analyzer.

For reference, readers in the EU will operate at 865-868MHz and in NA at 902-928MHz.

Comment: I should also add, that readers in many regions (ex: NA) can't be instructed to use a specific channel at any given time. Regulatory requirements from the FCC force the device to hop channels in a psuedo-random order and to dwell on each channel for equal time (when averaged over 20s).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I more thing i want to ask you about hop table index. I have a fixed hop table index for my equipment and there are 50 different frequency values between 903 to 928 MHz. The mean of these values are 915 MHz which is sort of standard value on which most UHF RFID system works. So how can i select the values here?. Do i select 915 MHz every time or is there any other way?. Thanks.

Comment: Hop Table index is given below:[915750,915250,903250,926750,926250,904250,927250,920250,919250,909250,918750,917750,905250,904750,925250,921750,914750,906750,913750,922250,911250,911750,903750,908750,905750,912250,906250,917250,914250,907250,918250,916250,910250,910750,907750,924750,909750,919750,916750,913250,923750,908250,925750,912750,924250,921250,920750,922750,902750,923250].

Comment: Yeah - that looks like a relatively standard hop table for north america. Who manufactures the reader? Many have FCC test modes that let you explictly set a single channel. This type of use is restricted to lab / development settings per the FCC and exposing the ability for end users to select a channel is forbidden. The big point here is the FCC mandates the reader has to hop through the table in pusedo random order (this means the channels are arranged randomly in  a list and the reader goes through the list sequentially). The FCC states the reader can't dwell on any one channel for > 400ms

Comment: Thanks. Let me give you little background of the project i am working on. I am actually working on finding the distance between a reader and a UHF passive RFID tag. I have a formula but i want to include frequency part to the formula as well because RSSI will change with different frequency at a particular position after the dwell time. So by adding frequency unit, I want to come up with a better formulation. So are you suggesting me that i can use the dwell time >400ms in the loop and then use the standard hop table for frequency to find distance. Reader is of Motorola.